# Rectangle Split in tikz Node using Loop Statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to dynamically loop through the Instruction Fields so as to draw the register containing them. The code I came up with is the following:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.multipart}

% Instruction fields
\def\fields{cond/31/28, op/27/26, I/25/25, cmd/24/21, S/20/20, Rn/19/16, Rd/15/12, rot/11/8, immeight/7/0}
\def\fieldlen{9}

% Instruction register
\tikzset{instr_reg/.style={
        draw, 
        thick,
        inner sep = 4pt,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts = \fieldlen, 
        rectangle split horizontal,
        anchor = center,
        minimum height = \cellheight,
    }
}

% Sizes
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bitnum}{32}
\def\scalefactor{100}
\def\cellheight{25pt}

\begin{document}

% Field widths
\foreach \field/\high/\low in \fields {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{((\high-\low + 1) / \bitnum) * \scalefactor}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname \field w\endcsname{\width mm}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   % Draw node
    \node[instr_reg] (adds_i) at (0,0) {
        \foreach \field/\high/\low [count=\i from 2] in \fields {
            \parbox[c][\cellheight][c]{\csname\field w\endcsname}{\centering \field}
        }
      };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but whenever I place `\nodepart{<number>}` below the `\parbox` tikz outputs an error concerning `\endgroup` or forgotten `}`.

The following is the wanted output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Your code compiles OK for me, though I'm not sure whether the output is what you want. What are you using to generate the error?

Comment: @cfr The code does not have an error. If I add the `\nodepart` it produces an error.

Comment: You need to use e.g. `\nodepart{two}bit for second part\nodepart{three}...` etc. There's no simple way of running this in a loop and I don't understand why you are using a `\parbox`.

Comment: @cfr I do not want a simple way. I want a way. If there is a way I would love to find out how to implement it. The `\parbox` is used to force the length of the parts to be variable, and exactly as I want it to be. I'm not sure there is another way to specify the length of the parts. If there is, feel free to suggest one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way vie package `bytefield`, which releases you from Tikz problems you describe:

- it's not based on Tikz
- you can include some Tikz, of course

This code is adjusted to the example on page 10 in the manual. Instetad of using `\bitbox` you can also use `\wordbox` for higher fields.

To process arbitrary registers you can create one ore more `\newcommand`s, with or without loops.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{bytefield}[ % not based on Tikz
    bitformatting={\small\bfseries},
    bitwidth=auto,
    endianness=big]{32}
    \bitheader{0-31} \\
    \bitbox{4}{cond} & 
    % ~~~ but include some Tikz if you like ~~~~~~~~~~
    \bitbox{2}{\tikz{\node{op} node[anchor=north,font=\tiny,blue]{00};}} & 
    \bitbox{1}{I} &
    \bitbox{4}{cmd} &
    \bitbox{1}{S} & 
    \bitbox{4}{$R_n$} & 
    \bitbox{4}{$R_d$} &
    \bitbox{4}{rot} & 
    \bitbox{8}{imm8} \\
\end{bytefield}


\end{document}
```